# Looping through Shiro LDAP Realm on Authenitcation Failure

Tags: ldap, jndi, shiro

I'm getting an odd error. If I pass in a valid user/password to my Shiro LDAP all is ok but if the combination is not valid it throws an exception and keeps on looping through the Shiro realm code. In the debugger it just stays in Shiro code except for my one override method:

```
  public class MyJndiLdapRealm extends JndiLdapRealm {


public MyJndiLdapRealm () {
    super();
}

@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo queryForAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token,
        LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory)
throws NamingException {

Object principal = token.getPrincipal();
Object credentials = token.getCredentials();

principal = getLdapPrincipal(token);

LdapContext ctx = null;
try {
     ctx = ldapContextFactory.getLdapContext(principal, credentials);

     //context was opened successfully, which means their credentials were valid.  Return the AuthenticationInfo:
     return createAuthenticationInfo(token, principal, credentials, ctx);
} finally {
    LdapUtils.closeContext(ctx);
}

 }



          <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/ldapLogin"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/ldapLogin"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/ldapLogin"/>      
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            [urls]
            /** = ssl[8443],authc, customAuthFilter
            [main]
            /logout = logout
        </value>
    </property>   
</bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
     <property name="realms">
        <list>
             <ref bean="authenticateLdapRealm"/>
             <ref bean="authenticateDbRolesRealm"/>
             <ref bean="DbAuthorizingRealm"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticator.authenticationStrategy">
        <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AllSuccessfulStrategy"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="authenticateLdapRealm" class="security.MyJndiLdapRealm">
    <property name="contextFactory" ref="contextFactory" />
    <property name="userDnTemplate" value="cn={0},ou=REMOTE,o=OFF" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="contextFactory" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory">
  <property name="url" value="ldap://172.25.3.91:389"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticateDbRolesRealm" class="security.DbRolesRealm">
</bean>

<bean id="SwiDbAuthorizingRealm" class="security.DbAuthorizingRealm">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my custom filter was the problem. Went to PassThruAuthenticationFilter and the problem was solved.